# I want to implement the TextWatcher interface for 2 EditText fields to show on TextView

Tags: android

**I want to implement the TextWatcher interface for 2 EditText fields to show on TextView.**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    TextView textView1;
    EditText editText1;
    TextView textView2;
    EditText editText2;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    editText1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    textView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    editText2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    textView2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);

    editText1.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
    editText2.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
  }

}
```

I'm using this

```
    editText1.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
    editText2.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
```

Answer (score 1):

try this in both editText, It will override textWatcher.....

```
editText1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

@Override
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}
});
```